Why is it necessary to perform DMA unmap immediately after a DMA transfer is complete?
According to DMA-API-HOWTO.txt:

"Streaming DMA mappings which are usually mapped for one DMA transfer, unmapped right after it (unless you use dma_sync_* below) and for which hardware can optimize for sequential accesses."

So, when sending the next DMA, a new buffer needs to be allocated, and a new IOVA-PA mapping must be created. Then why do we bother to unmap after every transfer? Is there a security-related reason for this?
The buffer that was already created should still be protected from other devices by the IOMMU, and the OS knows that the buffer is for DMA, so there's no reason to write other data there. What kind of security issue could there be, then?
